# retrieve a user profile in facebook while sharing a link

Tags: facebook

how to retrieve a user details in facebook while sharing a link? Please help

Comment: show us .htaccess files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with 1&1 where the default version of PHP enabled is below the minimum requirements of CakePHP 2.2. All you need to do is edit the `.htaccess` at the root of your application and add the following declaration: `AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php`

I found this guide if it's any help: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/php-5-4